# Is there a method for evaluating JS in Hermes directly from native code?

Tags: react-native, react-native-native-module, react-native-hermes

I'd like to implement some cross-platform functionality in JavaScript with one gotcha: it needs to be called from native code and *synchronously*. My understanding is that the JavaScript bridge only supports asynchronous message passing. While The New Architecture offers synchronous calls between from JavaScript to native code, my app cannot be updated to adopt it at this time. Is there any way to bundle pre-compiled JavaScript into a React Native app and execute it in Hermes directly from native code without using the bridge?